# Undefined reference, template struct and constexpr static member

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, static-members, constexpr

I got some problem with a static constexpr member of a template struct. The code compiles but I get linking error. Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
template<int n>
struct Test {
    static constexpr auto invoke = make_tuple(2, "test", 3.4);
};

template<typename T>
void test(T&& t) {
    cout << t << endl;
}

int main() {
    test(get<0>(Test<2>::invoke));
    return 0;
}
```

I got linking errors with that, so I tried this:

```
template<int n>
struct Test {
    static constexpr auto invoke = make_tuple(2, "test", 3.4);
};

// declare it outside the class
template<int n>
constexpr decltype(Test<n>::invoke) Test<n>::invoke;

template<typename T>
void test(T&& t) {
    cout << t << endl;
}

int main() {
    test(get<0>(Test<2>::invoke));
    return 0;
}
```

But instead I got this strange error:

```
error: redefinition of 'invoke' with a different type: 'const decltype(Test<n>::invoke)' vs 'const std::tuple<int, const char *, double>'
```

A different type??
Obviously, the non-template version works just fine:

```
struct Test {
    static constexpr auto invoke = make_tuple(2, "test", 3.4);
};

constexpr decltype(Test::invoke) Test::invoke;

template<typename T>
void test(T&& t) {
    cout << t << endl;
}

int main() {
    test(get<0>(Test::invoke));
    return 0;
}
```

How can I get the template version to work? Thank you very much

Comment: I added C++14 since `make_tuple` is not constexpr until then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I get the template version to work?

FWIW, your method works fine on my desktop, which uses g++ 4.8.4.

You can use:

```
template<int n>
constexpr decltype(make_tuple(2, "test", 3.4)) Test<n>::invoke;
```

The following also works on my desktop:

```
template<int n>
struct Test {
    static constexpr auto invoke = make_tuple(2, "test", 3.4);
    typedef decltype(invoke) invoke_t;
};

template<int n>
constexpr typename Test<n>::invoke_t Test<n>::invoke;
```

Comment: The only solution that seems to work is `decltype(make_tuple(2, "test", 3.4))` I'm using GCC 5.2.0 and Clang 3.7.0

Comment: That's strange that g++ 5.2.0 doesn't work while g++ 4.8.4 works.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you are running into an interesting corner case with decltype, this is covered in the clang bug report  [Static constexpr definitions used inside template](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=13517) which has the following example with a similar error as yours:

> This compiles fine, but when I make the class A, a template like this:
>
> ```
> struct L
> {
>     void operator()() const
>     {}
> };
>
> template<class X>
> struct A
> {
>     static constexpr auto F = L();
> };
>
> template<class X>
> constexpr decltype(A<X>::F) A<X>::F;
>
> int main()
> {
>     A<void>::F();
>     return 0;
> }
> ```
>
> Clang crashes, if I change the definition line for F to this:
>
> ```
> template<class X>
> constexpr typename std::remove_const<decltype(A<X>::F)>::type A<X>::F;
> ```
>
> Then clang produces this error:
>
> ```
> error: redefinition of 'F' with a different type
> constexpr typename std::remove_const<decltype(A<X>::F)>::type A<X>::F;
>                                                                     ^
> note: previous definition is here
>     static constexpr auto F = L();
>                           ^
> ```

and Richard Smith's reply was as follows:

> This error is correct. 'constexpr' and 'auto' are red herrings here.
>   Reduced testcase:
>
> ```
> template<class X> struct A { static int F; };
> template<class X> decltype(A<X>::F) A<X>::F;
> ```
>
> Per C++11 [temp.type]p2, "If an expression e involves a template
>   parameter, decltype(e) denotes a unique dependent type." Therefore the
>   type of A::F does not match the type in the template.

the full quote for that from the C++14 draft is as follows:

> If an expression e involves a template parameter, decltype(e) denotes
>   a unique dependent type. Two such decltype-specifiers refer to the
>   same type only if their expressions are equivalent (14.5.6.1). [ Note:
>   however, it may be aliased, e.g., by a typedef-name. —end note ]

The only obvious way I can see to get this work is:

```
template<int n>
constexpr decltype(make_tuple(2, "test", 3.4)) Test<n>::invoke;
```

No work around was offered in the bug report.